# Why are we not allowed to write Big-O notation in terms of fractions? Ex: O(n/2)

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

For example, the average case for linear sort is described as O(n). But why is it not described as O(n/2), wouldn't it be this way because the average is *the average* times the program runs?

Comment: Aside from the fact that big-O notation means we are ignoring constant factors like your $\frac12,$ why would the average be $\frac n2$? You can get $\frac n2$ if the running time is equally likely to be any number from $0$ to $n$; is it plausible to say a linear sort is equally likely to end in $1$ step or $n$ steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the same statement because we have :
$$O(n) = O\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$$

Saying that a function $f$ is $O(n)$ means that there is an $N$ and some $K>0$ such that :

$$ \forall n > N, |f(n)| \leq Kn$$

So in particular we have .

$$\forall n > N, |f(n)| \leq (2K)\frac{n}{2}$$

We prefer to say $O(n)$ for simplicity.

Hence note that in general we have :

$$O(n) = O(Kn), \text{ for some } K > 0$$